# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1568] vs. [32,49]

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

my keras encoder-decoder code works fine on cpu. but on gpu I cannot launch it with batch_size other  than 1 ! This is strange. Even when I do not use batch size argument in this fitting I get:

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1568] vs. [32,49]

(by default keras takes batch_size=32)

I can run many other programs with whatever batch_size I want. Wht module is comparing a two dimensional object with one dimensional ?

Comment: to those getting similar error can check this link as well github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11749 - changing the metrics used could help in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is similar, but I get:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:
>   Incompatible shapes: [64] vs. [128].

I found that it may be because the loss function does not perform dimensionality reduction operations.
So, I tried `tf.reduce_mean()`, it shows ok.